# Regards, Me - bye bye? or not to bye bye?

Tags: discussion

So it just hit me:

OP sign in their questions with:

- Regards, XXXXX
- Thank you, YYYYYY
- Please help...

I was just wondering, what do you think? shall we leave these endings? edit them out? or ask OP's to remove them?

I don't remember seen these on SF/SU and others, but here I feel I see more and more of these.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stackoverflow discourages the use of signatures and salutations. I tend to agree that these should be edited out to keep the questions as neutral as possible.

[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

> In general, taglines and signatures are strongly discouraged, and are
>   likely to be edited out. We don't want to clutter up the questions
>   page with a lot of redundant signature blocks and taglines and so
>   forth.

Comment: I'm even against thanks as it's really just clutter. +1 for killing all taglines and sigs.

Comment: I don't delete them from posts just for the sake of it, but often if there's something there and I'm editing the post for other reasons then I'll clean those up too.

Answer (score 11):

It does not bother me when someone types "Thank you" at the end of the question that they post.  To me, that's just being polite and I see nothing wrong with it.

Long signature blocks at the end of every question and answer are annoying, though, so we could edit those out.

Also, I don't think they are needed in answers.

Regards,

Peter Knolle ;-)

Comment: ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^

Comment: Agree with Peter. Nothing wrong in thanking the community. Signature blocks are definitely not required though.

Answer (score 5):

I feel thanks should be accepted but not something like a persons signature or a firm name .

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a huge uptick in signatures. As a community, we need to Edit these out of those posts. It doesn't provide any value and it makes questions seems like they are specific to a user which defeats the purpose of the site.